# Compiling Scala 2.10-RC3 macros in sbt project

Tags: sbt, scala-2.10, scala-macros

I am using SBT for my project, and I decided to add macros to it recently.

So I followed the examples in this project:

https://github.com/adamw/scala-macro-debug/tree/15fc8af48a6e7772c44b726513949a8ac9c9e3b7

In `project/Build.scala` I have this:

```
object ScalaMacroDebugBuild extends Build {
  import BuildSettings._

  lazy val root: Project = Project(
    "root",
    file("."),
    settings = buildSettings) aggregate (macros, src)

  lazy val macros: Project = Project(
    "macros",
    file("macros"),
    settings = buildSettings ++ Seq(
      libraryDependencies <+= (scalaVersion)("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % _)))

  lazy val src: Project = Project(
    "src",
    file("src"),
    settings = buildSettings) dependsOn (macros)

}
```

My directory structure is:

```
                     MyProject
           src                  macros          project         build.sbt
    main         test                       Build.scala
scala   java   scala java
```

So SBT has been compiling everything under src, and that works fine.

But when I compile the files in the macros directory, it is not being made available to the files in the src directory, so I get a compilation error.

How do I compile my macros and then have them available so the project using it can find it?

Comment: The build configuration looks correct.  It might help to format your directory structure description.  That way, we can tell if something is wrong there.  Otherwise, you might need to show sample code and the error message.

Comment: @MarkHarrah - Sorry, I thought it was formatted.  Just did that.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry.  It is just a bit different than the usual output of something like `tree`.  I'll give a proper answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The normal source directory is `<project-base>/src/main/scala`.  In the example, the existence of a project whose base directory is `MyProject/src/` confuses things.

First, there is the root project, whose base directory is `MyProject` and thus gets its main Scala sources from `MyProject/src/main/scala/`.  The `src` subproject's base directory is `MyProject/src/` and gets its sources from `MyProject/src/src/main/scala/` (the double `src/` is intentional).

So, the solution is probably to rename the base directory for the `src` project and then put the sources in the expected directory layout.

You can use `show root/compile:sources`, `show src/compile:sources`, `show root/compile:source-directories`, etc... to view what sbt thinks are the sources and source directories.  This can help confirm that things are as you expect and given insight to what might be wrong.  See also the `inspect` command.

Comment: I will look at what you suggested.  My build.sbt is in the MyProject directory, so the root of the ordinary source is src/... and macros is where my macros are, at the same level as src.

Comment: I added to my directory hierarchy to show where build.sbt is located.